# Multiple variables in a string

Tags: python, subprocess

I want to run some bash commands from Python. I've already been able to do it with `subprocess.Popen`. In some cases I want to add some arguments to the command like 'stdin' or 'cwd'. The thing is that I want to automate something, so I want to put the commands with its parameters on a file.

I'm using a structure like this:

```
this is a command that I want to execute, stdin=example
this is another command
I execute a third command, cwd=folder/
```

In my python script, I read line by line, and do something like this:

```
line = line.split(",", 1)
cmd = subprocess.Popen(line[0].split(" "), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

and I want to add one more parameter that can make generic the other parameters. I know that something like

```
cmd = subprocess.Popen(line[0].split(" "), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, cwd="folder/")
```

works, but I would like to put something like

```
cmd = subprocess.Popen(line[0].split(" "), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, line[1].split(",")) (maybe I should put another delimiter for the args)
```

but this doesn't work.

I'm not sure how to phrase this nor what are the concrete concepts this is using, so if the answer could be complete in this sense I'd be really grateful.

Comment: Honesty question:  if you are running bash-code using `subprocess.Popen` line-by-line, why not just use a bash script then?

Comment: I need to check in the middle some stuff with the output, like errors and stuff like that. I know very little of bash, and found out that I could do it with python. Also, when the process finishes I need to verify another stuff that has nothing to do with bash

Comment: well, you could run the entire script from Python. And then do the other stuff.

Comment: You mean to run it from bash and then do the other stuff?

Answer (score 0):

When `line = line.split(",", 1)` is executed, it creates a list of 2 elements.

For the first entry it's `["this is a command that I want to execute", " stdin=example"]`

But notice how in the second element (" stdin=example") the fist character is a space. This happens because `line.split()` is called with only a comma as delimiter, not comma **and** space.

The solution for this is to change the `","` to `", "`.

Not sure if this is what's causing your problems though...

Comment: It's not. I tried deleting that space and throws "positional argument follows keyword argument".

Comment: @DaniSeidler Right. Then try it like this: `cmd = subprocess.Popen(line[0].split(" "), line[1].split(","), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)` (Basically move the positional in front of the keyword argument)